# Bind a collection to a model in Backbone

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, backbone.js, client-side, backbone-events

I have a server side class:`TopicsListModel`
with properties as follows:

```
public class TopicsListModel
{
    public TopicsListModel()
    {
        ChildTopics = new HashSet<TopicsListModel>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TopicsListModel> ChildTopics { get; set; }
}
```

There is a function which returns a List,

```
public JsonResult SearchTopic(String topic)
    {
        var topics = LandingManager.SearchTopics(topic);
        //return Json(topics);
        return new JsonResult { Data = topic, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

I need to add this to the Backbone model and collection. I am a newbie to Backbone and I am struggling as you can guess. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want to build a model which will store data like:

```
{    name: "Model1",    id: 1,    submodels: [{ name: "Submodel1", id: 2 }, { name: "Submodel1", id: 2 }] }
```

I am unable to do so, I am having trouble setting up the basic collection like that, the ASP.NET MVC code part which returns the data I have shared. Sharing whatever I have done in the Backbone:

```
TestBB = function () {
if (!window.console) window.console = { log: function () { } };

var treeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var treeSubModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var treeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: treeSubModel,
    initialize: function () {
        console.log('Collection Initialized');
    }
});
var treeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#tree-view'),
    initialize: function () {
        //            this.collection.bind("render", this.render, this);
        //            this.collection.bind("addAll", this.addAll, this);
        //            this.collection.bind("addOne", this.addOne, this);
        _.bindAll(this);
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log("render");
        console.log(this.collection.length);
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        this.addAll();
        var template = _.template($("#template").html(), {});
        this.el.html(template);
    },
    addAll: function () {
        console.log("addAll");
        this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    },
    addOne: function (model) {
        console.log("addOne");
        view = new treeView({ model: model });
        $("ul", this.el).append(view.render());
    },
    events: { "click #btnFind": "doFind" },
    doFind: function (event) { alert('event fired'); }
});

return {
    TreeView: treeView
};} (Backbone);
```

Please suggest.

Comment: I think possibly you could try making your question a little more specific. You don't make it clear whether you're having trouble with the basics of collections fetching, or sub-collections, or specifically with fetching from ASP.NET. You could also show us what you've tried so far, to see if we can debug some actual code.

Comment: @stusmith: sorry about the binding part, I got that wrong :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved
I figured out the approach and defined the model and populated it!

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a case of 'binding' the collection to the back-end, as such: you `fetch` a collection from the server to read, and `save` (via sync) to write.

Firstly you'll need to let the collection know where the data resides by setting the `url` property. See: http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url.

Secondly you'll need to actually retrieve the data using the `fetch` method. See http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch. Note this is asynchronous, so you'll need to wait for the `success` callback.

To save data, use the `save` method on individual models. See http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save.

Comment: Not very enlighting(very general considering above case & a newbie!), perhaps you can elaborate to the mentioned context i.e. setting up the Model and the Collection.